# Using AWS elasticbeanstalk, when I do 'git aws.push' where in the filesystem is the application pushed?

Tags: git, amazon-web-services, ssh, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Using AWS Elasticbeanstalk, I push my code using 'git aws.push'.
When I then log into the linux box with ssh, where can I expect to find my project folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On linux ami I think these are the two possibilities, it might be different if you arent using the php container.  /var/app/current if the deployment was successful and /var/app/ondeck if something failed

Comment: sorry if successful its /var/app/current